# I'm having trouble with data in Datetime2 format while parsing data in array with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, substring

I want to select a row data group in the table based on the id coming to the `upNews()` method. Then I want to show some column values (like `Id`, `Name`, `Date`) on the alert screen after I split the data in the selected row. I am having trouble retrieving and/or parsing `Datetime2` format data contained in the array. How can I run this with Ajax?

```js
var selectedValue;

function upNews(pid) {
    var table = $('#kt_datatable').DataTable();
    selectedValue = table.data().filter(x => x.Id == pid)[0];
    $('#idd').val(selectedValue.Id);

    $('#nm').val(selectedValue.Name);

    /* I'm having trouble using the substring() method. */
    $('#dt').val(selectedValue.Date.text.substring(0,10));

    alert(selectedValue.Date);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--what data are you getting, and what do you want it to end up being?

Comment: There is a data named 'date' and its type is datetime2 . When I click on the function, I want to cut the data with substring.